# How do i call this method again on button_click

Tags: c#, forms, events, button

So what i have is basically this:

```
public partial class ShowList : UserControl
{
    public int count;
    private static LoadMovies lm = new LoadMovies();
    public List<Movie> movieList = lm.GetMovieList();

    public ShowList(string genreTitel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ......
        ......
        Load(genreTitel)
    }

    public void Load(string genreTitel)
    {
        lm.ReadMoviesToList();
        string picturepath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Pictures" + @"\Pictures\";
        IEnumerable<Movie> genreMovieList =
        movieList.Where(m => m.MovieGenres.Contains(genreTitel) && m.MovieNumberOfRatings > 80).Take(20);

        Movie movie1 = genreMovieList.ElementAt(count);
        label29.Text = movie1.MovieName;
        pictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile(picturepath + movie1.MovieId + ".jpg");
        label24.Text = "Rating: " + Math.Round(movie1.MovieAverageRating, 2);
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        //HERE I NEED SOME CODE TO RELOAD LOAD-METHOD.
    }
```

What i have tried, is to just write Load(); but as the method needs the genreTitel. And i cant reach the genreTitel.
How do i increment count, and reload Load(genreTitel) when clicking on button?

Answer (score 0):

Save genreTitel (title?) to a private variable. In the constructor assign the passed in to the new private variable, then you can access it from the Btn_Click.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a string genreTitel (or name it whatever you want) under your movielist declaration and then before you call Load(genreTitel) the first time in the constructor, do:

this.genreTitel = genreTitel.

This way you have a genreTitle variable accessible to the rest of the class

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're getting `genreTitel` from some form field, you can access that field in your Click Event Handler.

Ergo, where you tried to put simply `Load()`, use `Load(formField.Text)`.

Edit: Just noticed that `ShowList(string genreTitel)` was a constructor, not a method.

In that case, instantiate a private variable and assign `genreTitel` to it in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
//declare the class level variable like this
private string mgenretitle;

public ShowList(string genreTitel)
{
    // initialize the variable over here like this
    mgenretitle = genreTitel;
    InitializeComponent();
    ......
    ......
    Load(genreTitel)
}
```

and then use it over here

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      count++;
      // call your load method over here
      Load(mgenretitle);
      //HERE I NEED SOME CODE TO RELOAD LOAD-METHOD.
}
```

Comment: That is not possible. I cant reach the variable in the constructor. That is my problem.

Comment: why it is not possible?

Comment: Sorry, missed the private string. This solved the problem! Thanks!